# PHP Post body is null with Retrofit when it's not null

Tags: php, android, post, kotlin, retrofit2

After moving the site to another server, my php api stopped working. Now my api consider that post body sent via Retorift is empty (although this is not), when if sending via, for example, reqbin, everything works

Logs

```
D/OkHttp: --> POST https://site-url
    Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
    Content-Length: 55
D/OkHttp: {"login":"*****","password":"******"}
    --> END POST (55-byte body)

D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK https://site-url (492ms)
    Server: nginx
    Date: Sat, 12 Oct 2019 19:52:40 GMT
    Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
    Connection: keep-alive
    X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.10
    Vary: Accept-Encoding
    MS-Author-Via: DAV
    X-Powered-By: PleskLin
D/OkHttp: login/password is null
D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (22-byte body)
```

PHP API

```
// Converts into a PHP object
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$login = $data['login'];
$password = $data['password'];

if (isset($_GET['type']) && $_GET['type'] != NULL) {
    switch ($_GET['type']) {
        case "auth":
            if($login != NULL && $password != NULL) {
                emailOrUsername($login, $password, $db);
            } else echo 'login/password is null';
        break;
        case "token":
            if($login != NULL && $password != NULL) {
                compareMailToken($login, $password, $db);
            } else echo 'login/password is null';
        break;
    }
}
```

*var_dump(file_get_contents('php://input')) returns string(0) ""*

Mobile Retrofit API

```
interface AuthApi {
    @POST("auth.php?type=auth")
    fun authWithPass(@Body loginBody: LoginBody): Call<AuthResponse>
}

class AuthResponse(
        @SerializedName("type")
        val type: AuthResponseType,
        @SerializedName("user")
        val user: User?,
        @SerializedName("message")
        val message: String)
```

LoginBody

```
data class LoginBody(val login: String, val password: String)
```

AuthModel

```
override fun authWithPass(onFinishedListener: AuthContract.Model.OnFinishedListener, email: String, password: String) {
    val authApi = RetrofitApi.getInstance().create(AuthApi::class.java)

    val loginBody = LoginBody(email, password)

    val authQuery = authApi.authWithPass(loginBody)
    authQuery.enqueue(object : Callback<AuthResponse>{
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<AuthResponse>, response: Response<AuthResponse>) {
            response.body()?.let { body ->
                onFinishedListener.onFinished(body.type, body.user, body.message)
            } ?: onFinishedListener.onFinished()
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<AuthResponse>, t: Throwable) {
            onFinishedListener.onFailure(t)
        }
    })
}
```

RetrofitObject

```
object RetrofitApi {
    private var BASE_URL = "https://site-url/"
    private var retrofit: Retrofit? = null

    fun getInstance(): Retrofit {
        if (retrofit == null) {
            val gson = GsonBuilder()
                    .setLenient()
                    .create()

            val logging = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
            // set your desired log level
            logging.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
            val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().apply {
                connectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                addInterceptor(logging)
            }

            retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .client(httpClient.build())
                    .build()
        }
        return retrofit!!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by a redirect (f.e from www.url to url, etc), which is why my `php://input` was empty.